# Add a field to an existing FormType and Entity of a third-party bundle

Tags: php, symfony

In my project I have included a third-party bundle via composer containing multiple forms like:

```
namespace acme\ContactBundle\Form\Type;

class PersonType extends AbstractType {

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
            ->add('firstname', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => 'person.firstname'
            ))
            ->add('lastname', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => 'person.lastname'
            ));
    }
}
```

Now I would like to add an additional field *before* `firstname` called `title`.

Is there a way to do this without touching the original code? Probably, I also need to alter the entity to add the additional database field.

Alternatively: Since I have write access to the third-party bundle, maybe there's a way to allow fields to be injected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a [form type extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_form_type_extension.html) which will add the field that you want to add like this:

```
// ...
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormTypeExtensionInterface;

class TitleTypeExtension implements FormTypExtensionInterface
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('title', TextType::class);
    }

    public function getExtendedType()
    {
        return PersonType::class;
    }
}
```

Make sure that your extension is registered as a service and tagged with the `form.type_extension` tag.

However, this will only add the form type after the already existing children. Can you explain why it is important for you to insert it at a particular position?

Comment: That looks great! Will try that later. 
The position is not that important, I only thought it would be a nice feature.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same with FOSUserBundle. |

You need to create a controller which will extends the third party controller. By this, we can overwrite their controller and have an extended functionality.

I imported their controller as follows.

```
use \FOS\UserBundle\Controller\SecurityController as BaseController;
```

and extended MyController with the BaseController. You method names should be the same as of third party bundle.

```
class MyController extends BaseController
{
    //extending base loginActionMethod.
    public function loginAction(Request $request)
    {
         //my code
    }
}
```

Similarly in your case.

```
namespace acme\ContactBundle\Form\Type;

use path_to_your_third_party_formtype as BaseType;

class PersonType extends BaseType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
            ->add('title', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => 'person.title'
            ))
            ->add('firstname', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => 'person.firstname'
            ))
            ->add('lastname', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => 'person.lastname'
            ));
        }
}
```

You also need to take care of the entity.

Hope it helps, 
Cheers.

Comment: Dont code inside the third party bundles as they will be removed and installed on new composer install..

Comment: I want to alter the original form. So wherever it is used throughout my application, I want it to have the additional field. But I guess this won't work. I didn't want to edit the third-party bundle inside /vendor. I actually have write access to the git repo of the bundle. Thank you anyway!

Comment: okay. thats another case then. normally when people dont have write permissions then they can use this technique. 
please mark it correct if it helped you. 
thanks.